# typeof Number equals Number

Tags: javascript, numbers, typeof

In JavaScript,

1. `typeof 42       === 'number'     //true`

evaluates to true. But..

2. `typeof Number   === 'number'    //false`

evalutes to false. And..

3. `typeof 'number' === 'number'    //false`

also evaluates to false.

Shouldn't comparison 2 or 3 evaluate to true?

Comment: Why do you expect `typeof 'number'` to return `'number'`? What do you expect `typeof 'foo'` to return?

Comment: I see now. typeof 'foo' returns 'string'. I guess I was confused because the return value of typeof is quoted.

Comment: `typeof` always returns a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Number`, `String`, and `Boolean` are all objects (and functions). `typeof` applied to any of them will return the value `"function"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

The value `'number'` is a string and therefore its type is `'string'`.

Answer (score 1):

`Number` is a function which you can use to wrap a native value into a `Number`object.
`Number` is the also the constructor of the `Number` type, if used with `new`, e.g.

```
new Number(42)
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

> A Number object is created using the Number() constructor.

So `typeof Number` is actually `"function"`.

On the other hand, `'number'` is a String, so `typeof 'number'` is `"string"`

Comment: Okay, thanks. And what about [] === [] //false? (Since typeof [] is  'object'?

Comment: @Kiwi1: Two different objects are never equal to each other. The *type* of a value and the value itself are different things. Two different values can have the same type. `(typeof 5) === (typeof 42)` is true, but `5 === 42` is false.

Comment: The two `[]` are two different object instances, hence different. Their type doesn't really matter here.